# how to save stimulsoft report js to server in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stimulsoft

I have a component for report designer and assign method to `onSaveReport` event but in that method my component memeber is `undefined`

```
    options: any;
    designer: any;
    public document: ReportDocument;

    reportBody = '';
    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.document = new ReportDocument();
        this.options = new Stimulsoft.Designer.StiDesignerOptions();
        this.options.appearance.fullScreenMode = false;

        this.designer = new Stimulsoft.Designer.StiDesigner(this.options, 'StiDesigner', false);
        var report = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
        var json = { "DataSet": [{ Id: "a", Name: "A" }] }
        var dataSet = new Stimulsoft.System.Data.DataSet("JSON");

        dataSet.readJson(json)
        report.regData("JSON", "JSON", dataSet);

        report.dictionary.synchronize();
        this.designer.report = report;
        this.designer.renderHtml('designer');
        this.designer.onSaveReport = this.onReportSave;
    }

    private onReportSave(e: any) {
        this.document.body = e.report.saveToJsonString(); // error is here
        
    }
}
```

this is error:

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'body')
> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'body') at $.onReportSave [as onSaveReport] (http://localhost:4200/features-stimulsoft-report-stimulsoft-report-module.js:1206:28) at $.invokeSaveReport (http://localhost:4200/assets/lazyBundles/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.designer.js:30:82619) at $.raiseCallbackEventAsync (http://localhost:4200/assets/lazyBundles/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.designer.js:30:86029) at http://localhost:4200/assets/lazyBundles/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.designer.js:30:78818 at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12178:35) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72788:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12177:40) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11946:51) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12259:38) at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12248:52)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to your class `this` inside `onReportSave` function because you pass your function reference to `onSaveReport` and since designer call your function `this` inside your function is belong to designer not your class and that is the cause of error this.document is undefined and you call body from an undefined, but you can change it with bind property

```
this.designer.onSaveReport = this.onReportSave.bind(this);
```

Now you set `this` inside your function to be `this` of your class.